# In Protocol Buffers, how to import a file from the upper level directory?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following code in a protocol buffer file(pcfg_lm.proto):

```
import "../types/language.proto";

package nlp;

message PCFGProto {
  required Language lang = 1;
}
```

And of course there is a proto file exists at ../types/language.proto. However, when I issue the command:

```
protoc pcfg_lm.proto --cpp_out=/tmp
```

Here is the error message:

```
../types/language.proto: File not found.
pcfg_lm.proto: Import "../types/language.proto" was not found or had errors.
pcfg_lm.proto:6:12: "Language" is not defined.
```

I think there must be some way to specify the file names in the upper level directories, without using the -I flag. But how do I do that?

Comment: I ran into the same problem but I don't remember the solution. IIRC the import path is interpreted relative to the directory where you call protoc, not relative to the current proto file itself. Or something like that...

Comment: Hell yeah, I just found some old proto code. It's as I described. I'm calling protoc from the projects base directory like `protoc --cpp_out= graph/node.proto graph/edge.proto` and in edge there is `import "graph/node.proto";` even though both files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the **--proto_path=** directive to specify which directories to search for imports. It can be used **multiple** times if needed.

The correct --proto_path will depend on how the package is defined in the imported file (language.proto).

1. If the imported file (language.proto) contains **package types;**

   specify **--proto_path=*Parent directory*** and change the import to

   import "types/language.proto";
2. If the imported file has no package

   specify **--proto_path=*Parent directory/types*** and change the import to

   import "language.proto";

Comment: can you also specify a jar in proto path?

Comment: @Brue Matrin,with python,your solution will give exception:pcfg_lm.proto: Import "language.proto" has not been loaded when run a python script that imported pcfg_lm_pb2.py

Comment: --proto_path= "It can be used multiple times if needed." - this is what helped a lot, thanks.