# Organize proto files into folder in Google Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

Currently, we have more than 100 proto files to define message and they are put in the same "prototypes" folder. Now they look a bit of mess, so I want to organize the proto files into folder, something like below:

Before organization:

```
prototypes/ProtoCmd1.proto
prototypes/ProtoCmd2.proto
prototypes/ProtoCmd3.proto
prototypes/ProtoMsg1.proto
prototypes/ProtoMsg2.proto
prototypes/ProtoMsg3.proto
```

After organization:

```
prototypes/Cmd/ProtoCmd1.proto
prototypes/Cmd/ProtoCmd2.proto
prototypes/Cmd/ProtoCmd3.proto
prototypes/Msg/ProtoMsg1.proto
prototypes/Msg/ProtoMsg2.proto
prototypes/Msg/ProtoMsg3.proto
```

The problem is after organization, the cmd-proto no longer see the msg-proto, so it is impossible to import msg-proto. Is there anyway to overcome this? As far as I google, there is no result, but maybe I've overlooked something? Any help is appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: how do you reference the other proto? `import "Msg/ProtoMsg1.proto";`?

Comment: @zapl No, I still import as "ProtoMsg1.proto"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5420169/995891 - you'll need to add a path like that to the import statements and if you don't call protoc from the right directory (in this case from "prototypes") specify the proto path to be the common parent directory.

Comment: @zapl Thank you so much! It is exactly what I'm looking for. Don't understand why Google don't include it in their Protobuf tutorial. Can you answer the question so I can accept your answer?