# How to parse Google Protocol Buffers .proto file with import statement

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers, proto

I have two .proto files:
example1.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example1;
import "pkt2.proto";
...
```

and pkt2.proto file.

When I trying parse example1.proto:

```
DiskSourceTree source_tree;
source_tree.MapPath("", ".");
MFErrorPrinter mf_error_printer;
Importer importer(&source_tree, &mf_error_printer);
importer.AddUnusedImportTrackFile(file_name);
const FileDescriptor* parsed_file = importer.Import(fn);
...
```

I got errors:

```
proto/example/example1.proto.. proto/example/example1.proto:51:24: Option "(pkt2.variable)" unknown.
proto/example/example1.proto:60:22: Option "(pkt2.variable)" unknown.
proto/example/example1.proto:70:27: Option "(pkt2.variable)" unknown.
proto/example/example1.proto:11:11: Option "(pkt2.output)" unknown.
proto/example/example1.proto: warning: Import pkt2.proto but not used.
```

How can I import/parse file?

**Edited**: After several tryouts, I found my mistake:

File names in two statements below:

```
source_tree.MapPath("", ".");
...
const FileDescriptor* parsed_file = importer.Import(fn);
```

has incorrect file names:

```
"."
"proto/example/example1.proto"
```

therefore importer can't find out "proto/pkt2.proto". Valid values are:

```
"proto"
"example/example1.proto"
```

Comment: You can use the --proto_path option to specify where imports com from. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420169/in-protocol-buffers-how-to-import-a-file-from-the-upper-level-directory/5439189#5439189

Comment: What are the contents of `pkt2.proto`?

Comment: It contains extensions like this:  message Packet {
        repeated Address source   = 1;
        ...
    extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
        pkt2.Output output = 50502;
    }

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    pkt2.Variable variable = 50503;
}

Comment: @BruceMartin the option `--protoIpath` assumes you are using the command line tool `protoc`, which he isn't.  He is compiling/importing the proto file at runtime.

Comment: @АндрейИванов Thank you for finding and posting the corrections to your code. I have also been trying to figure out how to get this to work.